# C++ Method Overriding from another Class in Composition

Tags: c++

How to override a method from another class?
The situation is the following:

```
class foot:
{
    void kick() { clumsyKick(); };
}

class person: /* Person has Foot */
{
    foot *personsFoot;
}

class soccerPlayer: /* SoccerPlayer has Foot too, but his foot is better */
{
    foot *soccerPlayerFoot;
}
```

Now I want to override the foot class Kick() method for the soccerPlayer class only with the following method (I understand syntax is not correct bellow):

```
soccerPlayer::foot::Kick() { expertKick(); }
```

Is it possible in C++? **What is the best workaround for such a situation?**

ps: I can't afford to create a derived class for each implementation of foot::Kick();

Comment: *I can't afford to create a derived class for each implementation of foot::Kick();* Do you want to expand on this? What is your concern? If they are *different* they should be... different. It is not clear what you really want to obtain, an option would be to parametrize `foot` or `foot::kick` to take a *quality* value, and have the `person` do the `kick`ing (by dispatching internally to it's foot)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Yes, I agree, the problem is that this approach would create dozens of derived classes for foot only (there are 3 other bases as well), which would increase complexity beyond acceptable. If I have to create derived class I'd ratter change the software architecture.

Comment: The problem with the question is that you are not really talking about a problem to solve, but about how to implement a solution that might not be appropriate. It is impossible to even offer pointers into the right direction when there is not enough information of the *real* problem. BTW, feet's don't kick, people with feet kick (in the same way that [cannons don't sink ships, pirates with cannons sink ships](http://826valencia.org/store/products/cannons-dont-sink-ships-pirates-with-cannons-sink-ships-poster/))

Comment: Your syntax is all wrong.

Comment: @David How many ships could a ship shinker _[sic]_ shink if a ship shinker could shink ships?#

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Your perspective of what kicks has just been very enlightening, it solves the problem.

Comment: @David Feet's _[sic]_ don't kick people, rabbits do!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: sue me :) One of these days we'll discuss in Spanish, then I'll get revenge!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The direct answer is that you cannot override a method of a composed class. Overriding is only possible with inheritance.

You could use other design patterns in this case, such as delegates. C++ doesn't offer delegates natively but you can simulate them or use a framework that provides an implementation. You could make the `foot` class take a delegate for the implementation of `kick` and supply an alternate one in the `soccerPlayer` class.

You can simulate a delegate using function pointers or using a single method abstract class. For instance you might create

```
class IKick{
    public:
    virtual void kick() = 0;
}
```

Then you can have specialized implementations of `IKick` provided by the classes that extend `person`.

Of course in order to make the kick method do anything useful you'll probably want to change the signature to have some parameters that pass state to and form the caller.

Comment: @fanl: Simple answer: redesign. But that of course cannot be hinted without a better description of the real problem

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas True, but yet debating on the available information of the topic may get us good results.

Comment: Definitely delegate pattern is the far better solution when method override is necessary on an object basis. Thanks miky.

Answer (score 1):

I can see what you are trying to do, but Miky Dinescu is correct, you cannot do this in the manner that you have described.

You could do this with inheritance, that is, have a generic Person object with a Kick method, and have a sub-class (SoccerPlayer) override that method:

```
class person: /* Person has Foot */
{
    virtual void kick() { clumsyKick(); }
}

class soccerPlayer: /* SoccerPlayer has Foot too, but his foot is better */
{
    virtual void kick() { expertKick(); }
}
```

However, you appear to be attempting to do this via composition, rather than inheritance. How about this:

```
class foot
{
    virtual void Kick() { clumsyKick(); }
}

class soccerFoot: foot
{
    virtual void Kick() { expertKick(); }
}

class person: /* Person has Foot */
{
    private foot *personsFoot;
    person(foot* theFoot)
    {
        personsFoot = theFoot;
    }
}

void main()
{
    person soccerPlayer = new person(new soccerFoot());
    person.Kick(); //output of expertKick();
}
```

This is just a suggestion - but there are a lot of ways to override *behavior,* which is what you appear to be trying to do, but you cannot override the actual method of another class without inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

I think David Rodríguez has pointed the correct way of dealing with this situation:

```
class foot:
{
    /* Foot internals */
}

class person: /* Person has Foot and uses it to kick */
{
    foot *personsFoot;
    void kick() { clumsyKick(foot); };
}

class soccerPlayer: /* SoccerPlayer has Foot too, but his KICK is better */
{
    foot *soccerPlayerFoot;
    void kick() { expertKick(foot); };
}
```